# Python json.loads() returns JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, api

I wanted to write a program that gives me a live feed of how much subscribers a youtube channel has. For this I used the google's api which give the info in a json file:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/wTcrqM2kHwjf7GxOEpSBk_lofRA\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/HhHZCWV2vASrbydwK9ItUgUm0X8\"",
   "id": "UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "19893639729",
    "commentCount": "0",
    "subscriberCount": "79695778",
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
    "videoCount": "3707"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Here's the code:

```
import json

json_str = '''{
 {
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/wTcrqM2kHwjf7GxOEpSBk_lofRA\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/HhHZCWV2vASrbydwK9ItUgUm0X8\"",
   "id": "UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "19893639729",
    "commentCount": "0",
    "subscriberCount": "79695778",
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
    "videoCount": "3707"
   }
  }
 ]
}
'''

data = json.loads(json_str)


print(data)
```

But when I try to convert it into a python dictionary using json.loads(), I get the following error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 2 (char 3)
```

Also:

```
print(ascii(json_str))
'{\n {\n "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",\n "etag": ""XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/wTcrqM2kHwjf7GxOEpSBk_lofRA"",\n "pageInfo": {\n  "totalResults": 1,\n  "resultsPerPage": 5\n },\n "items": [\n  {\n   "kind": "youtube#channel",\n   "etag": ""XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/HhHZCWV2vASrbydwK9ItUgUm0X8"",\n   "id": "UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw",\n   "statistics": {\n    "viewCount": "19893639729",\n    "commentCount": "0",\n    "subscriberCount": "79695778",\n    "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,\n    "videoCount": "3707"\n   }\n  }\n ]\n}\n'
```

What's causing the problem?

Comment: How exactly are you passing this JSON in? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: The JSON you posted decodes just fine, no issues. The problem lies elsewhere. When the exception occurs, use `print(ascii(jsonstring))` to give us an accurate representation of the problematic string.

Comment: Your string definition is invalid, because ``\`` escapes are lost as they are interpreted by *Python* as part of the string literal syntax. Double the ``\`` escapes to ``\\`` or use a raw string definition (`r''''...'''`).

Comment: You can see your error in the `"etag": ""...` part of the output of `print(ascii(...))`, see those doubled double quotes? The backslash that the JSON parser needs to handle that quote value is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the following code I was able to open your JSON and print it. Save your JSON to temp.json and try this:

```
import json

with open("temp.json", "r") as infile:
    data = json.loads(infile.read())

print(data)
```

Comment: This Worked!, what I don't get is why it was not working when the entire string was assigned to a variable.